# Why is it that wrong return for bst scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I want to create a bst, but my result always get root and null, I can not find a reason, need help, thanks

like so

```
(struct tree-node (val left right) #:transparent)

(define (tree-add tree value)
  (if (null? tree)
      (tree-node value null null)
      (let ([x (tree-node-val tree)])
        (cond
          [(= value x) tree]
          [(< value x)
           (tree-add (tree-node-left tree) value)]
          [(> value x)
           (tree-add (tree-node-right tree) value)])
        tree)))
```

Comment: The value of the `cond` expression is discarded; that branch is equivalent to `(let ([x (tree-node-val tree)]) tree)`, which is equivalent to `tree`.

Comment: Ah， thats make sence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test your code with some numbers and see, what kind of result is returned. Your code returns:

- `tree` if the inserted number is equal to `(tree-node-val tree)`
- `(tree-node value null null)` if the inserted number wasn't in the tree

But you probably want to return the full structure, with the new number inserted. So, in each recursive step, you have to create `tree-node`, which will have the same values as the current node:

```
(tree-node (tree-node-val tree)
           (tree-node-left tree)
           (tree-node-right tree))
```

, but its left/right node will be different (the following code is for situation, when you insert a number into a left node of the tree):

```
(tree-node (tree-node-val tree)
           (tree-add (tree-node-left tree) value)
           (tree-node-right tree))
```

Full code:

```
(struct tree-node (val left right) #:transparent)

(define (tree-add tree value)
  (if (null? tree)
      (tree-node value null null)
      (let ([x (tree-node-val tree)])
        (cond
          [(= value x) tree]
          [(< value x)
           (tree-node x
                      (tree-add (tree-node-left tree) value)
                      (tree-node-right tree))]
          [(> value x)
           (tree-node x
                      (tree-node-left tree)
                      (tree-add (tree-node-right tree) value))]))))
```

Examples:

```
> (tree-add (tree-add (tree-add (tree-add '() 3) 4) 2) 1)
(tree-node 3 (tree-node 2 (tree-node 1 '() '()) '()) (tree-node 4 '() '()))

> (foldl (lambda (n tree) (tree-add tree n))
         '() '(3 1 2 4 5))
(tree-node
 3
 (tree-node 1 '() (tree-node 2 '() '()))
 (tree-node 4 '() (tree-node 5 '() '())))
```