# When I doing tree-depth function, it got a mistake

Tags: scheme, racket

I got a error, when I run it always say:

```
 tree-node-left: contract violation

  expected: tree-node?

  given: '()

(struct tree-node (val left right) #:transparent)
(define (tree-depth tree)
  (if (empty-tree? tree) 0
      (+ 1 (max (tree-depth (tree-node-left tree))
                (tree-depth (tree-node-right tree))))))
```

Comment: You provided an input that was not a well formed tree.

Comment: What input did you provide? What is the definition of `empty-tree?`?

Comment: `empty-tree`  is null tree.            I add like what you did in my another question,  but when I  add (tree-node 3 (tree-node 2 (tree-node 1 '() '()) '()) (tree-node 4 '() '())) in my this method, it said error.

Comment: 1. What are you using as empty tree?, 2. what does `empty-tree?` look like?. It seems to me like it does not accept the empty list as the empty tree so that means that either your `empty-tree?` is not well implemented or your input uses `'()` as the empty tree where your model uses something else to indicate the empty tree.

Comment: the `empty-tree` is `(struct empty-tree () #:transparent)`

Comment: @GaryXiong Ok, so you construct a one node tree like `(tree-node 1 (empty-tree) (empty-tree))`? I bet you use `'()` which isn't of type `empty-tree` such that the code assumes the empty list is a `tree-node`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For context, this question is follow-up of: [Why is it that wrong return for bst scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73563733/why-is-it-that-wrong-return-for-bst-scheme)

If you don't have to use `(struct empty-tree () #:transparent)`, I would represent an empty tree as an empty list, as I already did in the previous answer. With that, you can rewrite `tree-depth` this way:

```
(define (tree-depth tree)
  (if (empty? tree) 0
      (add1 (max (tree-depth (tree-node-left tree))
                 (tree-depth (tree-node-right tree))))))
```

Test:

```
> (tree-depth (tree-add (tree-add (tree-add (tree-add '() 3) 4) 2) 1))
3
> (tree-depth (tree-add '() 3))
1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to use the `empty-tree` type, use that and not the empty list in your tree:

```
(define (leaf v) (tree-node v (empty-tree) (empty-tree)))

(define a-tree
  (tree-node 3 (tree-node 2 (leaf 1) (empty-tree))
               (leaf 4)))

> (tree-depth a-tree)
3
```